# Need help understanding union of subspaces textbook example

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning about intersections, sums, and direct sums of subspaces. My linear algebra textbook has the following example on the union of subspaces:

*In the real vector space $\mathbb{R^2}$ (thought of as the xy-plane) the $x$-axis $X=\{[x\ 0]^T:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $y$-axis $Y=\{[0\ y]^T:y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are subspaces, but their union is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ since $[1\ 0]^T+[0\ 1]^T=[1\ 1]^T\notin X\cup Y$.*

What would $X\cup Y$ be? And does it contain the zero vector? I know that a subspace must contain the zero vector, and $[1\ 1]^T$ does not contain the zero vector, right?

Comment: The union is just the two axes.

Comment: The final sentence is telling you this: $[1\ 0]^T$ is in $X\cup Y$. And $[0\ 1]^T$ is in $X\cup Y$; if $X\cup Y$ were a subspace, then the sum of two vectors in the set would have to be in the set. But the sum of these two vectors, which *are* in the set, is $[1\ 1]^T$, which is **not** in $X\cup Y$. So $X\cup Y$ is not closed under sums of vectors, and hence cannot be a subspace.  Your final question does not literally make sense, since $[1\ 1]^T$ is a *vector*, not a set of vectors, so you can't ask if it "contains" the zero vector.

Comment: "*$[1~1]^T$ does not contain the zero vector*"  Uhm... $[1~1]^T$ is *a* vector... a particular element of the space $\Bbb R^2$, just like the zero vector is.  It doesn't make sense to talk about a vector "*containing another vector*"... you should treat them as being "*on the same level as one another.*"  The question was whether or not the set $X\cup Y$ contained the zero vector since that is the set we are curious about asking if it was a vector subspace.

Comment: As for $X\cup Y$., it is the set of all elements who are either elements of $X$ (*and so have second coordinate equal to zero*) or are elements of $Y$ (*and so have first coordinate equal to zero*).  This set *does* happen to contain the zero vector (*since the zero vector happens to be an element of $X$ for instance*) and also happens to be closed under scalar multiplication.  It failed to be a subspace because it fails to be closed under addition, as shown by the counterexample provided.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok. I did not realize $[1\ 1]^T$ was a vector.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why is $[1\ 1]^T$ not in $X\cup Y$?

Comment: Because it is not in $X$ (because the second coordinate is not $0$) and it is not in $Y$ (because the first coordinate is not $0$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok thank you.